# Find element in Map with Map.pick

Tags: f#

I have something similar top this:

```
let idx = 9
let map = 
    Map.empty.
        Add(10, "abc").
        Add( 9, "bcd").
        Add( 8, "cde").
        Add( 7, "def")
let result = 
    map 
    |> Map.pick (fun key value -> if idx > key then Some(key) else None)
printfn "%A" result
```

[Map.pick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/map.pick%5B'key,'t,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) from MSDN: `Searches the map looking for the first element where the given function returns a Some value.`

I assume that searching is starting from the end of the map - from 7 towards 10, since the result is 7.

But I want to get the process to start from 10 towards 7, and then I will get 8. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maps are stored in order of their key because of the way the data structure is designed. Map functions like `pick` happen to start from the smallest key, but it's not something that you should rely on either way.

If this is the main way that you are using this map, then a map may not be the best choice of data structure for your overall task. But if you do need to use a map, I would suggest this:

```
map 
|> Map.toSeq
|> Seq.filter (fun (key, _) -> idx > key)
|> Seq.map fst
|> Seq.max
// returns 8
```

Be aware that if the there are no keys that meet the criteria then `Seq.max` will receive and empty sequence and throw an exception.

Comment: Ok, what data-structure is better in this case?

Comment: If this is all you're doing with it then a sequence or array or list of tuples might be more suited. Once advantage of the map is that it guarantees no duplicate keys. The best choice would also be determined by where the data comes from and how it is built up.